# Using intent://swfUrl in webView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I am loading a url in `webView` that this url work with `Adobe Connect` :

```
https://online.xxx.xxx/common/html/mobile/locale/en/get.html?launchParams=swfUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fonline.xxx.xxx%252Fcommon%252FmeetingAS3%252Fshell%252Fshell.swf%253Froom%253D871935%253Bsession%253Dbreezbreezsrqdnu9pdpbgdcze%2526ticket%253Dp82xcuhciqyi%2526proxy%253Dfalse%2526appInstance%253D7%252F871935%252F%2526aicc_url%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fonline.xxx.xxx%25252Fservlet%25252Fverify%25253Fsco-id%25253D871935%2526host%253Donline.xxx.xxx%2526path%253D%25252Fr3hu4se31fc%25252F%2526sco-id%253D871935%2526session%253Dbreezbreezsrqdnu9pdpbgdcze%2526ticket%253Dp82xcuhciqyi%2526transcript-id%253D1722746%2526protos%253Drtmp%253A1935%252Crtmpt%253A443%2526origins%253Dlocalhost%253A8506%2526edges%253Donline.xxx.xxx%2526lang%253Den%2526account_id%253D7%26htmlUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fonline.xxx.xxx%252Fr3hu4se31fc%252F%253Flauncher%253Dfalse%26mode%3Dauto%26lang%3Den%26close_meeting%3Djavascript%3Awindow.close%28%29%3B&appPackage=air.com.adobe.connectpro&locale=en&type=meeting
```

I have the application `Adobe Connect` on my mobile and I select `Open Adobe Connect Mobile` from above url, when I select this item get me bellow url :

```
intent://swfUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fonline.xxx.xxx%252Fcommon%252FmeetingAS3%252Fshell%252Fshell.swf%253Froom%253D871935%253Bsession%253Dbreezbreezsrqdnu9pdpbgdcze%2526ticket%253Dp82xcuhciqyi%2526proxy%253Dfalse%2526appInstance%253D7%252F871935%252F%2526aicc_url%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fonline.xxx.xxx%25252Fservlet%25252Fverify%25253Fsco-id%25253D871935%2526host%253Donline.xxx.xxx%2526path%253D%25252Fr3hu4se31fc%25252F%2526sco-id%253D871935%2526session%253Dbreezbreezsrqdnu9pdpbgdcze%2526ticket%253Dp82xcuhciqyi%2526transcript-id%253D1722746%2526protos%253Drtmp%253A1935%252Crtmpt%253A443%2526origins%253Dlocalhost%253A8506%2526edges%253Donline.xxx.xxx%2526lang%253Den%2526account_id%253D7%26htmlUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fonline.xxx.xx%252Fr3hu4se31fc%252F%253Flauncher%253Dfalse%26mode%3Dauto%26lang%3Den%26close_meeting%3Djavascript%3Awindow.close%28%29%3B#Intent;scheme=connectpro;package=air.com.adobe.connectpro;end
```

And for this url I wrote bellow code for redirect user to application of `Adobe Connect` but I can't redirect user to application :

```
    urlListClassWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (url.startsWith("intent://") && url.contains("https")) {
                String urls = Uri.decode(url);
                String bkpUrl = null;
                Pattern regexBkp = Pattern.compile("intent://(.*?)#");
                Matcher regexMatcherBkp = regexBkp.matcher(urls);
                if (regexMatcherBkp.find()) {
                    bkpUrl = regexMatcherBkp.group(1);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://" + bkpUrl));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem :

```
if (url.startsWith("intent://swfUrl")) {
    try {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent().parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
        if (intent != null) {
            view.stopLoading();
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (info != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

    }
}
```